# Can musl libc be built on OS X?

Tags: macos, building, musl

I'm trying to build [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) on a machine running OS X 10.11.5. Unfortunately, I get the following error while running `make`:

```
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fexcess-precision=standard' is not supported
clang: warning: optimization flag '-frounding-math' is not supported
<inline asm>:6:1: error: unknown directive
.weak _DYNAMIC 
^
<inline asm>:7:1: error: unknown directive
.hidden _DYNAMIC 
^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [obj/crt/Scrt1.o] Error 1
```

I'm using Clang 7.3.0 (703-0-31) and I'm using the source pulled from the musl repo at `git://git.musl-libc.org/musl`.

Comment: Are you trying to use musl as a native OS X library? That will take more work than just getting it to compile.

Comment: Same problem with clang-1200.0.32.2

Comment: @Olsonist check out user5555713's answer — musl relies on some directives which aren't supported in macOS, and others which _may_ be supported under a different name but possibly without identical behaviour. I never followed up on the musl mailing list but if you're pursuing this that'd be a good place to start with dev questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are OS X assembler errors and this means that it is different from a GNU as in the way it understands special weak and hidden symbol definitions in object files.

While `.weak` directive is [possibly supported by Apple as as `.weak_definition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html), `.hidden` is an ELF specific (OS X uses Mach-O binary file format).

Comment: I understand the original issue, but thanks for trying to find alternative instructions; I'm still wondering if there isn't an already-modified version of the library which would build on OS X.

Comment: Join and ask musl mailing list, last time I've heard of at least two forks for FreeBSD and Win32. There is also ongoing port to barebones hardware.